# Submit, Show Results, delay 3 seconds and redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I've got a form where users can input data and the behavior that I'm looking for is after the submit, the code behind writes to a database and returns a response of success to the page. I currently have this code working. The next item that I'd like to have happen is redirect after the successful message but I'd like to delay for 2 or 3 seconds allowing the user to see the success message before redirecting.

Behavior: Submit -> Show Success Message -> Delay 3 seconds -> Redirect

I'm currently developing this in VB; however I'm fine with examples in either VB or C#. This is a traditional web form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like this approach, although some of the already proposed are very good:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "success", "alert('Submitted Successfully.'); setInterval(function(){location.href='http://www.google.com';},3000);", true);
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You can use Thread.Sleep() method. Just add this before the Response.Redirect i.e.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
Response.Redirect("MyURL");
```

Alternatively, You could add delay in Response header like this

```
Response.AddHeader "REFRESH","3;URL=MyURL"
```

The number denotes above is delay value in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can use html [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) tag

Just place the following cod in head section on your page containing success message.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL='http://nextpageurlaftersuccess.com/'">
```